# Debounce function meaningless line

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have a `debounce` function taken from web.

```
function debounce(f, ms) {
    let timer = null;

    return function(...args) {
        const onComplete = () => {
            f.apply(this, args);
            timer = null;
        }

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }

        timer = setTimeout(onComplete, ms);
    }   

}
```

Why exactly do we need this line `f.aply(this, args)`, if we can just change this line to `f(args)` and result will be same.

Comment: No, `this` will be different.

Comment: the apply is used to pass the `this` context to the `f` method

Comment: @deceze can you please give me an example. I know how apply is used commonly, but in this manner, i see no actual difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invoke your debounced function without `this`:

```
let deb = debounce(...);
deb()
```

there's no difference.

If you invoke it with `this` (via `bind/call/apply`), you do need the `apply` line to pass `this` correctly to the source function:

```js
"use strict";

function debounce(f, ms) {
    let timer = null;

    return function(...args) {
        const onComplete = () => {
            console.log('with apply:')
            f.apply(this, args);
            console.log('without apply:')
            f(...args)
            timer = null;
        }

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }

        timer = setTimeout(onComplete, ms);
    }   

}

let x = {y: 1};
let deb = debounce(function() { console.log(this)}, 3);
deb.apply(x)
```

Comment: Yes, i know how apply works, in this case it will `console.log()` x from context you pass into it, but why i can't broke my debounce function like this, without using `apply` it is still works as expected

Comment: @Kraken: if you replace the `f.apply` line with `f(...args)`, the above example will log `undefined` instead of `{y:1}`.